# Skipping __init__.py files with iSort

Tags: python, python-3.x, isort

I am working on a python package and in order to format imports I run isort on all the python files. I would like iSort to skip `__init__.py` files as in some (rare) cases the order of the imports is critical and does not line up with isort's ordering scheme.

I tried playing around with different configuration options in my `pyproject.toml` file and I believe I am looking for the `extend_skip_glob` [configuration option](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#extend-skip-glob). However, the issue is I am unable to figure out a glob pattern that matches any `__init__.py` file located in any subdirectory of `src` (where the code lives) located at any depth (I believe that's part of the issue I am experiencing).

I have tried a few combinations listed below, but none of them appear to be working.

```
[tool.isort]
# option 1
extend_skip_glob = ["__init__.py"]

# option 2
extend_skip_glob = ["src/**/__init__.py"]

# option 3
extend_skip_glob = ["src/**/*init__.py"]
```

Has anybody encountered something like this before and figured out a way to solve it?

Comment: Just curious, why does the import order matter in your case?

Comment: @d-k-bo I have a few cases where I get circular import errors if I run isort through it.  It's only an issue in a handful of files so figuring out how to tell isort to ignore those files seems like the easier solution in the short term. Perhaps I could just add those individual files, but I know that this will always be constrained to the __init__.py files and I would like to catch all future instances automatically rather than have to add them manually.

Comment: I think cyclic imports should always resolved by restructuring the project (eg. moving some part to a different module), using `if TYPE_CHECKING: from ... import ...` if its caused by type hints, using `import ...` instead of `from ... import ...` or by relying on lazy imports if possible.

Comment: If you want to keep everything as it is and can't find a working config for isort (sorry, I can't help you with this), there is also the dirty approach to insert a noop statement (like a string literal) between those import to keep them separated

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `skip` instead. In `pyproject.toml` file for example,

```
[tool.isort]  
skip = ["__init__.py"]
```